# ElasticSearch converting old query

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-6

I need to translate OLD queries from ES2.0 to ES6.1 ... and it seems not easy at all ...
the original one is :

```
{
    "size":0,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": {
                        "query": {
                            "match": {
                                "my_hits": {
                                    "query": 0,
                                    "type": "phrase"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "fields": "ip",
    "aggregations": {
        "par_ip": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "ip",
                "min_doc_count": 2,
                "size": 10000,
                "order": {
                    "_term": "asc"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I think that the first part could be converted to :

```
{
 "size": 0,
 "query": {
    "match" : {
        "my_hits": "0"
    }
  }
}
```

but for the rest I am stuck ...

> "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
>   "reason": "Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. Set fielddata=true on [ip] in order to load fielddata in memory by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can however use significant memory. Alternatively use a keyword field instead."

EDIT :  I think you will need thoses informations :

`"mappings": { ...
 "ip": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },`

Thanks for your help !
Stéphane

Comment: to delete !!!!!

Comment: i think it's the `"fields": "ip"` line that is causing the trouble. Try removing it? 
If it works, try with `"fields": "ip.keyword"`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to preserve the filter clause, which will not take scoring into consideration, so no result ordering control, one possible translation would be:

```
{
    "size":0,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": {
              "match_phrase": {
                "my_hits": "some query"
              }
          }
        }
    },
    "stored_fields": "ip",
    "aggregations": {
        "par_ip": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "ip",
                "min_doc_count": 2,
                "size": 10000,
                "order": {
                    "_term": "asc"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

here also change `fields` field to `stored_fields`, the `match` query with type `phrase` is now a `match_phrase` query.
In case you want the query to influence the score of the results, you should avoid the `filter` clause:

```
{
    "size":0,
    "query": {
       "match_phrase": {
          "my_hits": "some query"
       }
    },
    "stored_fields": "ip",
    "aggregations": {
        "par_ip": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "ip",
                "min_doc_count": 2,
                "size": 10000,
                "order": {
                    "_term": "asc"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

you will have to mark the `ip` field as stored `"store": true` in the mapping if you want to retrieve it as a `stored_field`

Comment: pfff I left ES too long, I am totally lost ... I tried to change the _mapping to include "store": true but with no success ""type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
        "reason": "Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [mappings : {doc={properties={@timestamp={type=date}, @version={type=text, fields={keyword={type=keyword, ignore_above=256}}}, " ... but I am not even sure that I use the good process ....